# JS renaming methods

Tags: javascript, methods, rename

I am fed up with writing and reading `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName`... makes programming harder for me.

So i want to rename them. I want them to be `getId`, `getTags` and `getClasses`.

It is a micro library what i am after. How can i get that result with minimum cpu usage?

At least the `var doc = document;` was easy.

Comment: So make your own functions and call them...

Comment: `var getId=document.getElementById.bind(document);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign them.

```js
var doc = document;
doc.getId = doc.getElementById;
doc.getTags = doc.getElementsByTagName;
doc.getClasses = doc.getElementsByClassName;
alert(doc.getId('foo').className);
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="classy"></div>
```

If you want to be able to leave out `doc.`, you'll need to define functions, e.g:

```
function getId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Comment: the console returns _Cannot get Property "getElementById" of undefined_ (to the first way)

Comment: It works when I try it. Are you sure you set `doc` before setting `doc.getElementById`?

Comment: Make sure all your uses of `doc` are in the scope where it was assigned.

Comment: copy/paste, but will continue trying

Comment: something has went wrog before. Thanks

Comment: do you know how to rename the `parentElement` to `parent`?

Comment: That requires modifying the prototype for DOM elements, which you're not supposed to do. You'll have to do it with an ordinary function.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first-class citizens in Javascript. You can assign them to variables. Therefore, you can assign new functions to `document` and they will be available.

`document.getId = document.getElementById;
document.getTags = document.getElementsByTagName;
document.getClasses = document.getElementsByClassName;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jQuery? getElementById becomes `$.("#theID")`. You can truncate the "selector" with `$`.

Comment: Every big library kills CPUs ... and that's not my style

Comment: It's all a matter of preference, for sure. You're not wrong. I didn't mean to sound like a jerk.

Comment: if the site eats the CPU, the site classes down (yet a bit)